# Sort multiple field in array object

Tags: javascript

I have array obj like this:

```
[{ A: '24/12/2020', J: 54106, }, { A: '10/dd/2020', J: 54103 }, { A: 'mm/29/2020', J: 54103 }]
```

I wanna sort J field first then sort A field .. but I have issue when I sort,
I wanna result like this :

```
[ { A: '10/dd/2020', J: 54103 }, { A: 'mm/29/2020', J: 54103 }, { A: '24/12/2020', J: 54106, }]
```

but data response is :

```
[{ A: 'mm/29/2020', J: 54103 }, { A: '10/dd/2020', J: 54103 }, { A: '24/12/2020', J: 54106, }]
```

My code here :

```
result.sort(function (a, b) {
  return parseFloat(a.J) - parseFloat(b.J) || (a.A) - (b.A);
});
```

I think it need sort from number to text but it's not like that

Comment: parentheses around a single value have no effect.

Comment: what is thew wanted order of the part date string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a compare function to sort it. First compare the J fields and then compare the A fields.

```js
const data = [
  { A: '24/12/2020', J: 54106 },
  { A: '10/dd/2020', J: 54103 },
  { A: 'mm/29/2020', J: 54103 },
];

const cmp = (x, y) => {
  if (x.J === y.J) {
    return x.A.localeCompare(y.A);
  }
  return x.J > y.J ? 1 : -1;
};
const ret = data.sort(cmp);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: I don't know why but it's not working when  "A": "mm/29/2020" is in first obj, check it: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0hb3yjqu/)

Comment: What is A field? Do you want to compare it as a date or string?

Comment: I just want to compare as string, I think number will be sort first then character, it's right?

Comment: I try with this data but not working too: ```const data = [
  {
    A: 'mm',
    J: 54103,
  },
  {
    A: '10',
    J: 54103,

  }
];
```

Comment: now check it and let me know it's working or not.

Comment: it's not working :( .. You can check here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/0hb3yjqu/)

Comment: You are using the old code. Replace it with the new one that I have just updated here. Just replace this line return y.A - x.A; with  return x.A.localeCompare(y.A);